# react-intl v4 upgrade `IntlProvider` not found preventing component from displaying when using `injectIntl` wrapper

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I am trying to upgrade from react-intl v 2.3.0 to 4.5.1. I have run into a few issues around the `injectIntl` HOC since the upgrade. I have a shared component library within a monorepo that is imported into different features (combination of imported shared and local unique components in a separate part of the repo). However, my `IntlProvider` lives in my shared components library and we import a component called `AppShell` that includes any needed providers (including intl) that wraps the top level of every feature.

I followed advice found on an issue on the formatjs repo and deleted the react-intl version from my shared component library. This solved most of my issues with a few caveats.

Note, all examples below are using a feature folder with react-intl version 4.5.1, and a shared component library having no version of react-intl installed

#### Fix attempt 1

If I try to use the `injectIntl` HOC from `react-intl` the component will not render on the page and I get the following errors:
[image]

[image]

code example (AppShell wrapper component lives in the top level `ReactDOM.render` function):

```
import { FormattedMessage, injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

// shared component library
import { Alert } from '@shared/components/alert';
// component custom to feature, also can contain shared components
import WorkspaceListContainer from './workspaceListContainer';
import messages from './messages';

export class AppLifecycleMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    const deleteAlertTitle = this.props.intl.formatMessage(
      messages.deleteAlertTitle,
      { alertName: name }
    );

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <WorkspaceListContainer />
            <Alert
                title={deleteAlertTitle}
                okButtonText={<FormattedMessage {...messages.deleteOkButton} />}
                cancelButtonText={<FormattedMessage {...messages.deleteCancelButton} />}
            />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default injectIntl(AppLifecycleMenu);
```

Note, in a lot of our shared components, `intl` messages can be passed in as props and some components are wrapped in their own `injectIntl` HOC to intl default versions of props (like a default button label).

#### Fix attempt 2

However, if I import an `injectIntl` helper we have in our shared resource library, the component renders but still displays an error message:

injectIntlHelper code:

```
// only apply intl in non-test environments
export  default  Component  => process.env.NODE_ENV  ===  TEST_ENV  ?  Component  :  injectIntl(Component);
```

code example (AppShell wrapper component lives in the top level `ReactDOM.render` function):

```
import { FormattedMessage, injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

// shared component library
import { Alert } from '@shared/components/alert';
import injectIntl from '@shared/utilities/injectIntl';
// component custom to feature, also can contain shared components
import WorkspaceListContainer from './workspaceListContainer';
import messages from './messages';

export class DeleteWorkspaceAlert extends Component {
  render() {
    const deleteAlertTitle = this.props.intl.formatMessage(
      messages.deleteAlertTitle,
      { alertName: name }
    );

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <WorkspaceListContainer />
            <Alert
                title={deleteAlertTitle}
                okButtonText={<FormattedMessage {...messages.deleteOkButton} />}
                cancelButtonText={<FormattedMessage {...messages.deleteCancelButton} />}
            />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default injectIntl(AppLifecycleMenu);
```

component tree with intlprovider:
[image]

Error message:
[image]

#### Fix attempt 3

I also tried only having `react-intl` installed in the shared resource library but that results in this error message:
[image]

#### Environment

I have tried going down versions in react-intl, but this issue persists back down into the 3.0 and up versions

I've been trying different combinations and looking online for a few days, are there any other changes I can make to get rid of these errors? Is anything jumping out as something I am missing adding or updating between versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this, my issue was solved by following/modifying the fix from the issue: https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/1620

Unlike the issue linked above, my projects `IntlProvider` lives in the shared resource library and is exported to wrap components. Therefore I deleted the `react-intl` dependency from all folders other than my shared resource library and exported any needed components from there.

So my imports in my non-shared components folder would look like

```
import injectIntl, { FormattedMessage, FormattedDate } from '@shared/utils/intl';
```

with component(s) in my shared library that have files that look like this

```
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl;
export FormattedMessage;
```

Relevant quote from the issue:

> I think the reason [having multiple dependencies] worked with older version is old React context API. New React context API rely on same reference. You project instantiates react context from different node_modules thus contexts are not same reference. This also means you are bundling react-intl twice in your application.